# Split two div text with a diagonal line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i tried different ways, but i can't find any way to do something like this through HTML, CSS.
At the moment I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="intro-slogan">
    <div id="diagonal"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#intro-slogan{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5em;
    clear: both;
    height: 100%;
}
#diagonal{
    background: red;
    width: 18em;
    height: 1px;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: According to your code, you basically did a diagonal red line right ?
Wouldnt it be easier to use a pre-made image ?

Comment: I don't see how this could be done with CSS. CSS is not all-powerful. The example you provided is an image. Just do an image.

Comment: actualy, it's a animation, but i can'f figure it out on this part. here is the original: http://giving.georgjensen.com/ . i think the best way is to use svg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fiddle**:  https://jsfiddle.net/avakqez9/1/

```
<div class="one">
  <h1>The Jocky</h1>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <h1>of Mocky</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -1px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.one h1 {
  margin-right: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.two h1{
  color: orange;
  margin: 40px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

Comment: The second div is slightly above the first on my version of Chrome. Adding `position: relative; top: 1px;` sorted it. I imagine getting it pixel perfect cross-browser might be tricky / impossible but if they're offset like they are in OP's question 1px is irrelevant.

Comment: Probably, that is just a mockup.

Answer (score 2):

You could try wrapping each one of the original divs in a container, skewing the containers with the [transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/) CSS3 property (check skewX and skewY) and skew the content div in the opposite direction (this way you keep the content non-skewed).

After that, perhaps `overflow:hidden` and some toying around with margins/paddings could finally do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position:absolute` , `z-Index` , `border` properties , using `span` element as descendant of `#intro-slogan` to position text "of giving" below text "the gift"

```css
#intro-slogan {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5em;
  clear: both;
  height: 100%;
  z-Index:0;
  font-size:24px;
}

#intro-slogan span {
  position:absolute;
  top:145px;
  left:74px;
}
#diagonal {
  background: red;
  width: 18em;
  height: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  position:absolute;
  left:-140px;
  z-Index:10;
  border:2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro-slogan">
  The gift<div id="diagonal"></div><span>of giving</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is kind of tricky becouse just few pixels are hidden. but like in the picture, i want the entire word to come from that hidden section. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

For those who still need, i made it this way:
HTML:

```
<div class='centerMe'>
        <div class='skew1'>
            <div class='text part-1'>
                <span>the Gift</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='skew2'>
            <div class='text part-2'>
                <span>of Giving</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.skew1,
    .skew2{
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 300px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        width: 27em;
        float: left;
        transform: skew(-20deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    }
    .text{
        top: 50%;
        color: #fff;
        right: 60px;
        font-size: 2em;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: skew(20deg);
        -o-transform: skew(20deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
        -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    }
    .skew2:before{
        content:'';
        top: 55%;
        left: 0px;
        width: 2px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
.centerMe{
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 1200px;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
```